# Angularjs - how to get count of 'li' in a list and width of list on-load

Tags: html, angularjs

Check my [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/1qa1PD4ZjxwxqkGAzaTw?p=preview), as you can see there are 10 menuitem, but the count is shown as 3.
I need to count the number of `li` and final width of `ul` on-load.
Please note I need count of `li` only as all `li` will be populated based on securitygroups, hence list will not contain all json item.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

 <body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="scrollController" >
 <input ng-click="myStyle={'margin-left': moveLeft()}" ng-disabled="leftdisabled" class="left" type="button" value="Move Left" />
 <div class="menucontainer left">
  <ul id="myMenuList" ng-style="myStyle">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"> <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>

    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<input ng-click="myStyle={'margin-left': moveRight()}" ng-disabled="rightdisabled" class="left" type="button" value="Move Right" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p >Need help: there are total 12 menu item, i want to get count of LI and width of UL</p>
please note i dont need count of 'item', i need count of 'li' after it's populated in 'ul' as there will be some security groups based on that only 'li' will be populated
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Angular Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('scrollController', function($scope) {
$scope.marginLeft = 0;

$scope.myStyle = {'margin-left': '0px'};
var items = [];
$scope.items = [{name:"111",age:25},{name:"222",age:25},{name:"333",age:25},{name:"444",age:25},{name:"555",age:25},{name:"666",age:25},{name:"aaa",age:25},{name:"bbb",age:25},{name:"ccc",age:25},{name:"ddd",age:25}];


 //need help here
 $scope.mml=angular.element(document.getElementById('myMenuList'));
 alert($scope.mml.children.length);

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be nice if you have a `$timeout` in your controller:

```
app.controller('scrollController', function($scope, $timeout) {
```

and because angular has the `jqLite` implementation you can use the `.find()` to find the list items available in the target `ul`:

```
  $timeout(function(){
     alert($scope.mml.find('li').length);
  }, 1000);
```

### [Plunkr here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0sebDRjP4jWNFHNqWeaY?p=preview)

---

As per your comment you can use `clientWidth` this way:

```
$scope.mml[0].clientWidth
```

This can give you the actual width of the element you are targeting.

### [Updated plunkr...](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rr7QDiKC83z0PUhq4HOz?p=preview)

Comment: please help in "how to measure width of UL"

Comment: @ankit its a late reply but you can see the updated part in the answer above with plunkr in action.

Answer (score 1):

You can create directive which will fire passed function on last repeated item.

```
app.directive('onLastRepeat', function($timeout) {
    return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$eval(attrs.onLastRepeat);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" on-last-repeat="countLi()"> <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a></li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.countLi = function(){
  $scope.mml=angular.element(document.getElementById('myMenuList'));
  alert($scope.mml.children().length);
}
```

Here is you updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4hRSj0axTcawamRCvVD6?p=preview

Comment: can you please update the plnkr as I am trying above suggestion but something going wrong

Comment: @ankit, there was a one more error in your code. You should use `$scope.mml.children().length` instead of `$scope.mml.children.length`. Link to updated plunkr is in my post.

Comment: trying to get width by this `alert($scope.mml.offsetwidth);` but it's showing undefined, please help

Comment: @ankit use `$scope.mml[0].offsetWidth` or include `jquery` to your project and use `$($scope.mml).width()`